# How can the awesome SO calendar widget be made to work in IE?

Tags: css

There is, what I think is one of the best uses of CSS over images (the calendar icon) located at: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/transcripts/139?offset=120

But it doesn't work in IE8.  Is it possible to convert this to work with IE?

I suppose we could use this jQuery code at: http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html

I guess to summarize, there's no equivalent in IE of the -moz-border-radius property, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [PIE](http://css3pie.com/about/), it claims to bring CSS3 to the IEs:

> CSS Level 3 brings with it some
>   incredibly powerful styling features.
>   Rounded corners, soft drop shadows,
>   gradient fills, and so on. These are
>   the kinds of elements our designer
>   friends love to use because they make
>   for attractive sites, but are
>   difficult and time-consuming to
>   implement, involving complex sprite
>   images, extra non-semantic markup,
>   large JavaScript libraries, and other
>   lovely hacks.
>
> CSS3 promises to do away with all
>   that! But as we all know, due to
>   Internet Explorer’s lack of support
>   for any of these features, **we must
>   be patient and refrain from using
>   them**, and make do with the same old
>   tedious techniques for the foreseeable
>   future.
>
> **Or must we?**

I'm looking at using it when it's time for my impending IE bugfix marathon.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a list of links for [Rounded Corners Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250413%28VS.85%29.aspx). The links includes great solutions for ie (not so great as border-radius of css3). I am sure you will find something for your needs.